# How to find empty bytes array

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

How to find out is bytes array has any data or it is newly created bytes array?

```
var Buffer = new byte[1000];
//How to find out is Buffer is empty or not?
```

Comment: Isn't there a function like Buffer.isEmpty()?

Comment: what do you mean by empty ? full of zero ?

Comment: c# do not provide such function.

Comment: Buffer is not a keyword under System? we can declare keyword as variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume by 'empty' you mean containing default values for every byte element, if this isn't what you mean, look at @sehe's answer.

How about using LINQ to check whether all elements have the default value for the type:

```
var Empty = Buffer.All(B => B == default(Byte));
```

Comment: `default(T)` would only have a meaning in the context of a template, IIRC

Comment: @sehe: Nope, it's a perfectly valid operator regardless of generics.

Comment: The `.All()` method on `System.Buffer` does not exist. Even if I include `System.Linq`.

Comment: @Robula I'm referring to the buffer variable in the question, rather than system.buffer

Answer (score 1):

A byte is a valuetype, it cannot be null;

Creating an array immediately initializes the elements to the default value for the element type.

This means, empty cells can't exist, let alone be detected.

If you must:

1. use nullable types

   `var Buffer = new byte?[1000];`
2. use [Array.Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) when capacity changes. However, you could soon be in a situation where just using a System.Collections.Generic.List would be much more efficient

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers given

```
            var buffer = new byte[1000];
            var bFree = true;
            foreach (var b in buffer)
            {
                if (b == default(byte)) continue;
                bFree = false;
                break;
            }
```